# Restricted cubic spline looks like a linear curve, but p for nonlinear < 0.001

Tags: r, regression, p-value, splines, rms

I am analyzing a association between a frailty index and care needs using the cox model. I use R and use rms package to fit restricted cubic spline.

This is my R code.

```
rcs_dt <- datadist(dt.care2020[, c(
    "care","care.py",
    "QQ")])
options(datadist = 'rcs_dt')
rcs_model <- cph(Surv(care.py, care) ~ rcs(QQ, 3),
                 data = dt.care2020, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
anova(rcs_model) # Nonlinear test
rcs_model <- update(rcs_model)
rcs_fit <- Predict(rcs_model, QQ,
                   ref.zero = TRUE,
                   fun = exp)
ggplot(rcs_fit, aes(QQ, yhat)) +
    geom_line(colour       = "Black",
              size         = 0.75) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10),
                       breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1),
                       expression(paste(
                           "",
                       ))) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 10), expand = TRUE) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(0, 10),
        breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1),
        "Hazard ratios and 95% confidence intervals"
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.subtitle    = element_text(vjust    = 1),
        plot.caption     = element_text(vjust    = 1),
        axis.line        = element_line(size     = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour           = "white"),
        axis.title       = element_text(family   = "Times",
                                        colour       = "Black",
                                        size     = 9),
        axis.text        = element_text(family   = "Times",
                                        colour       = "Black",
                                        size     = 9),
        panel.background = element_rect(
            fill     = "gray99",
            colour   = "white",
            linetype = "twodash"
        ),
        plot.background  = element_rect(fill     = "white")
    ) +
    labs(caption = NULL) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed")
    )
```

This is result p for Nonlinear.

```
> anova(rcs_model) # Nonlinear test
                Wald Statistics          Response: Surv(care.py, care) 
 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 QQ         474.35     2    <.0001
  Nonlinear  25.65     1    <.0001
 TOTAL      474.35     2    <.0001
```

This is the restricted cubic spline.
[image]

This is the restricted cubic spline for all cause mortality. The event number is about 200, which is smaller than cases of care needs event (about 900), so the confidence interval is wide.

[image]

Is this normal？ How to explain this results？

Comment: How many data points do you have? Judging from the confidence band, it's probably a lot, especially for lower values of `QQ`. We have [lots of threads about the fact that p values get very small for even trivial departures from the null hypothesis as the sample size increases](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bstatistical-significance%5d%20sample%20size&searchOn=3). And your departure from linearity is clear enough for large values of `QQ`. A small p value does not mean a result is "large" or "important", only that it is unlikely to occur under the null hypothesis.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. The population size is 3599, and most participants have a low QQ score. So, because the sample is large, the nonlinear part make the nonlinear p value  a small value. right? In fact, I also analyzed mortality as outcome in this sample. The mortality cases is about 200 and care needs cases is about 900 during the follow-up. The p for nonlinear is 0.85 (I will add the spline in this post). So, I am worrying maybe I had a mistake in R codes or I misunderstand the method. So, in your opinion, the results is normal (not strange). Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right!

Comment: That looks curved to me.

Comment: What is the x-axis even? Care needs as a semi-continuous variable? You should inspect HRs on the *log* scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That looks curved to me. No, it is not wiggling all over the place, but there is curvature upon visual inspection.
2. A highly significant p-value despite only modest curvature can be interpreted just like any other hypothesis test that catches a modest effect. I will venture a guess that you have a fairly large sample size. Consequently, your hypothesis test has considerable power to detect even small deviations from the null hypothesis of no curvature.

Together, I would view the results as saying there is strong evidence of slight curvature.